# Component rerender state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
export const Component = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

    const sendMessage = msg => {
        socket.emit('message', msg);

        setMessages([
            ...messages,
            {
                content: msg.content
            }
        ])
    };

    const onMessage = msg => setMessages([
        ...messages,
        {
            content: msg.content
        }
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('message', onMessage)
    }, []);

    return (
        <button onClick={() => sendMessage({content: 'test'})}/>
    )
};
```

This is my example code of how I achieve sending/getting a message. The issue is that messages are always rerendered if I'm getting messages from a socket (onMessage). Everything is fine and messages are filling if I'm doing it by `sendMessage` function.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I've solve this issue, there is answer:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('message', onMessage)
    }, [messages]); //rerender if messages changed
```

But I don't understand why this resolve my issue. Can somebody explain?

EDIT 2:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('message', onMessage)
        return () => {
          socket.off('message', onMessage);
        }

    }, [messages]); //rerender if messages changed
```

What do you think about this solution?

Comment: Can you also add the snippet where you are rendering the list of messages?

Comment: Your question is not completely clear to me. Can you elaborate more? By the way, useState method will be called every time your component updates with new messages. Which will result in adding multiple 'onMessage' handler to the socket. After some time, only 1 message will result in so many re-renders. I suggest you to read and understand useEffect hook properly

Comment: You're right, it will add listener each time but without that, it will not work. (messages always be an empty array). I've edited my answer (look at EDIT 2).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a simple case of `closure` when you set an event listener method to socket during the initial load, the `onMessage`even along with its lexical scope is being used. However during next subsequent renders a new onMessage is created with its updated lexical scope which isn't being reassigned to `socket event` so it references the `messages` value inside of it which was present during the initial load.

However if you write your effect to execute on each message change, the new onMessage method created on messages change re-render is being assigned to socket event and it works correctly.

However a better solution than to use `messages` as a dependency in `useEffect` is to use state update callback

```
const onMessage = msg => setMessages(prevMessages => ([
    ...prevMessages,
    {
        content: msg.content
    }
]));

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('message', onMessage)
    return () => {
      socket.off('message', onMessage);
    }
}, []);
```